# Python: Tallying the number of unique sizes in a list

Tags: python

Word Problem:

Pant Sizes

A store marketing manager has a chronological list of pant sizes sold to customers for a particular style of pant sold during a promotion. A tally of each unique size is required. Write and test a function that given a list of sizes, returns a new list with each size followed by its tally (total number sold).

Function Definition

```
def tally(sizes: list) -> list:
```

Example input:

```
a = [30, 34, 30, 20, 34]

print(tally(a))
```

Example output:

```
[30, 2, 34, 2, 20, 1]
```

So far I created a function that returns a new list with the unique values and I need help including the tally beside the value. I was thinking about creating a accumulator but I don't know the number of unique values in a list

```
sizes = [30, 34, 30, 20, 34]

unique = []
for i in sizes:
    if i not in unique:
        unique.append(i)
        
print(unique)
```

Comment: I noticed that you have asked several questions on SO now, all of which have had several answers, and you haven't marked any of them as answered.  Assigning a correct answer isn't mandatory but it is encouraged, and having a pattern of not doing so can lead to downvotes and less people willing to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick to using only lists, then you could keep track of the tally in a separate list and then merge the two lists at the end.

```py
sizes = [30, 34, 30, 20, 34]

unique = []
tally = []
for i in sizes:
    if i not in unique:
        unique.append(i)
        tally.append(1)
    else:
        idx = unique.index(i)
        tally[idx] += 1
result = []
for i in range(len(unique)):
    result.append(unique[i])
    result.append(tally[i])

print(result) # [30, 2, 34, 2, 20, 1]
```

if you are okay with using a dictionary which is the better/more efficient way then you could do something like this:

```
sizes = [30, 34, 30, 20, 34]

unique = {}
for i in sizes:
    if i in unique:
       unique[i] += 1
    else:
       unique[i] = 1
result = [j for i in unique.items() for j in i]  
print(result) #  [30, 2, 34, 2, 20, 1]
```

Comment: Using two passes to first get the unique values, then count them is not ideal (especially when the number of duplicates increases). Using `count` repeatedly is worse, this gives a quadratic complexity as you'll need to read the list again for each item.

Comment: `[(i, sizes.count(i)) for i in set(sizes)]` is an anti-pattern, as noted in the previous comment and you should really just use a `collections.Counter`

Comment: @mozway That isn't what I am doing.  Both of my first two examples gets the unique items and counts in the first pass.  All the second part is doing is putting them into the format the OP requested which is exactly what your code does in your answer except using a different data structure

Comment: @Alexander well, your first example is using the data structures that are inefficient for this problem, it is polynomial time when it could just be linear time (like your second example)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  that is intentional.  If you notice the OP is  using a list to collect the items and the output is a list as well.  That is why in my answer I clearly state that if the OP wanted to stick to using lists... then that was one way of doing it

Comment: Nowhere does the OP state that this is a requirement, you are simply infering that from their own code, which is mostly incomplete anyway. But more importantly, you shouldn't use inefficient code like that with at least *telling people* that it is inefficient, especially when the canonical, dict-based, efficient solution is pretty straightforward

Comment: @Alexander my comment was mostly for the repeated count (this should absolutely be avoided), the second approach is fine (you could use `setdefault` to avoid the conditional, though). The first approach should use a set to collect the unique values (lists are inefficient for this purpose).

Comment: When I answer questions I try to use as much of the OP's code as possible so that they can directly see how to get to a solution using their own code.  I realize that this may sometimes lead to a less efficient solution than is possible, but I think the OP benefits the most from seeing how their own code can be transformed to a solution

Answer (score 2):

If you want to learn python, learn how to use the builtin modules.

Here using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and a list comprehension.

```
def tally(l):
    from collections import Counter
    return [x for t in Counter(l).items() for x in t]

tally([30, 34, 30, 20, 34])
# [30, 2, 34, 2, 20, 1]
```

If you don't want to use a module, you can code your own `Counter` (quite easy for a simple count).